# How to make new directories inherit their parent's ACL?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, files, acl

I have set default permissions for new files and groups in my directory like this

```
sudo setfacl -d -m g::rwX /<directory>
```

It works great. 
The problem is, that if I create any new files or directories in child directories of `<directory>`, the ACL I set no longer affects them.
How can I make sure that the permissions above will also be applied to any new files or directory which are located anywhere  under `<directory>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-Rdm` (recursive) options.

- R for recursive
- d for future changes; the R takes care of everything below it.
- m for add and modify rules.

Comment: That worked but it somehow managed to break my g+s i had on the parent directory. Now only new files in the parent directory inherit the group, any new files i make in the sub directories of the parent dir just have my user name as a group